# Lucene 4.3.1 backup process

Tags: java, lucene, backup

I have a working Lucene 4.3.1 cluster, and I'm adding an automatic hot-backup process, similar to what's described in the **"Lucene in Action"** book from Manning, and several blog posts out there.  However, the book is based on Lucene 2.3, and the API has changed slightly in 4.3.1.  The book says to instantiate the `IndexWriter` like so:

```
IndexDeletionPolicy policy = new KeepOnlyLastCommitDeletionPolicy();
SnapshotDeletionPolicy snapshotter = new SnapshotDeletionPolicy(policy);
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, analyzer, snapshotter,
                                 IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
```

And when doing a backup:

```
try {
   IndexCommit commit = snapshotter.snapshot();
   Collection<String> fileNames = commit.getFileNames();
   /*<iterate over & copy files from fileNames>*/
} finally {
   snapshotter.release();
}
```

However, it seems this changed with Lucene 4.x at some point. The SnapshotDeletionPolicy is now configured with the IndexWriterConfig, and that's passed in when creating the IndexWriter. This is the code I have up to now:

```
public Indexer(Directory indexDir, PrintStream printStream) throws IOException {
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_43, new Analyzer());
    snapshotter = new SnapshotDeletionPolicy(new KeepOnlyLastCommitDeletionPolicy());
    writerConfig.setIndexDeletionPolicy(snapshotter);
    indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDir, writerConfig);
}
```

And when starting the backup, you can't just do `snapshotter.snapshot()`.  You now have to specify an arbitrary `commitIdentifier` id, and use that after you're done to release the snapshot.

```
SnapshotDeletionPolicy snapshotter = indexer.getSnapshotter();
String commitIdentifier = generateCommitIdentifier();
try {
    IndexCommit commit = snapshotter.snapshot(commitIdentifier);
    for (String fileName : commit.getFileNames()) {
        backupFile(fileName);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Exception", e);
} finally {
    snapshotter.release(commitIdentifier);
    indexer.deleteUnusedFiles();
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working.  Regardless of whether there have been docs indexed or not, and regardless of whether I have committed or not, my call to `snapshotter.snapshot(commitIdentifier)` always throws an `IllegalStateException` saying `No index commit to snapshot`.  Looking at the code, the SnapshotDeletionPolicy seems to think there have been no commits, even though I'm committing to disk every 5 seconds or so.  I've verified, and there are docs being written and committed to indexes all the time, but `snapshotter` always thinks there have been zero commits.

Can anybody tell me what I might be doing wrong?  Let me know if I need to post more details.

Comment: The Lucene/Solr mailing lists are likely to be more help. And what is a 'Lucene Cluster?' Do you mean Solr?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I did get help on the Lucene mailing lists, thanks for pointing that out.  By "Lucene cluster" I meant a home-grown Solr-like cluster, but without using Solr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted this same question to the Lucene java-user mailing list, and got an answer almost immediately.   The problem is that the SnapshotDeletionPolicy you use to configure the `IndexWriter` initially, is NOT the same one that the IndexWriter uses.  On construction, the `IndexWriter` actually clones the `SnapshotDeletionPolicy` you passed in, so the first block of code above should look like this instead:

```
public Indexer(Directory indexDir, PrintStream printStream) throws IOException {
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_43, new Analyzer());
    writerConfig.setIndexDeletionPolicy(new SnapshotDeletionPolicy(new KeepOnlyLastCommitDeletionPolicy()));
    indexWriter = new IndexWriter(indexDir, writerConfig);
    snapshotter = (SnapshotDeletionPolicy) indexWriter.getConfig().getIndexDeletionPolicy();
}
```

Notice the last line, where you're setting the snapshotter to the `IndexDeletionPolicy` from the IndexWriter config.  That's the key.  After that, the second chunk of code detailed in the original question works perfectly.

For reference, [here's the answer](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/201307.mbox/%3CCALfq-2TnpY-K86jwv3trr1ctrWAaa7pKGTXrzjxZ0mtcDnL9ng@mail.gmail.com%3E) I got from the Apache Lucene mailing list.